# Html2Canvas ...Google Map is not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I am running a Apache Server . I have a simple screen capture set up using Html2canvas .The capture function is rendering a blank Image . I have tried numerous ways to configure the javascript using related articles from this site to no Avail . The code is all working and tested because I can capture the image prior to "google  maps api being loaded . Thank you and any advice would be much appreciated .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <head>

    <title>Tester</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAwbkbZLyhsmTCWXbTcjbgbRSzHs7K5SvaUdm8ua-Xxy_-2dYwMxQMhnagaawTo7L1FE1-amhuQxIlXw"></script>
    <script>
google.load("earth", "1");

var ge = null;

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance("map_canvas", initCallback, failureCallback);
}

function initCallback(object) {
  ge = object;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
}

function failureCallback(object) {
}



    function capture() {
        $('#target').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                //Submit the form manually
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        });
    }





    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      #map_canvas {position: fixed; top: 60px;
            left: 0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; }

    #target {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 0px;  padding:0px; position: absolute; left: 10px;top: 80px;height: 580px; width: 580px;
    }


</style>

  </head>

  <body onload='init()' id='body'>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot Of Div Below" onclick="capture();" />

<div id="target">
                   <div id="map_canvas"> </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the php document renders to save.php

```
<?php
//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);
?>
<h2>Save the image and show to user</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="img.png" target="blank">
                Click Here to See The Image Saved to Server</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="index.php">
                Click Here to Go Back</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>
                Here is Client-sided image:
            </span>
            <br />
<?php
//Show the image
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';
?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
body, a, span {
    font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

This sample works Correctly . I want to achieve this with above Code using "Google Earth"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
          zoom:5,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(window).load(function(){

    $('#load').click(function(){

            html2canvas($('#googleMap'), {
            useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

                window.location.href = dataUrl;
                                    }
            });

    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="load"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can get the map image from google, but html2canvas can't see it

Comment: Yes This is Correct ... It will load successfully. I have another sample of a successfule screen capture while its in "google Maps " I am using google earth so the syntax Has to change . In which I am not able to figure out . I will post it . Thank you for your interest .

Comment: The Html2Canvas is not recognizing the Page is loaded . The Google Maps working example demonstrates how to Load the document and successfully captures the screenshot . I tried to change the javascript in My first example to match the "working" example.  I keep getting errors in the method in which I try to "load " the document . I need to capture to occur with the "capture " button and its all giving me trouble :) . Thank you Mr  DanDavis...

Comment: I'm just playing with something similar myself. I actually see all the markers and other elements, just not the map itself it renders a grey empty background.

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046778/html2canvas-does-not-work-with-google-maps-pan#answer-24281734

Answer (score 3):

Since I was just having a similar problem and I managed to solve it maybe this will help you too.
It turns out to be a problem with loading images from a different (external) domain. In our case the external domain is something like maps.googleapis.com.
html2canvas allows us to use a proxy to solve that problem so instead of directly trying to load the images cross-domain we use the local proxy to retrieve the images, save them and pass them on to html2canvas.

I personally used this proxy: [PHP html2canvas proxy](https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy)

Just download it and then make sure to create the data directory that the proxy uses exists and is writable. By default the directory is called 'data' and it should be in your webroot.

Then change the piece of JavaScript to use the proxy:

```
html2canvas($('#googleMap'), {
    proxy: 'html2canvasproxy.php',
    useCORS: false,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

        window.location.href = dataUrl;
    }
 });
```

Also make sure to set useCORS to false, because you can't use both a proxy and have useCORS enabled.

Comment: O Wow Thank You Ruben for your time and advice . I will try your solution asap. Am excited to see the results . Thank you again Ruben Have awesome day /Night

Comment: @ericmaxfield Awesome, let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: i just want to add, in case you are using php and still get failure when retrieving the images, you must have the extension openssl enabled. (to get images from google maps)