# How to change view angle in Google Static Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Is it possible to change the angle of view in google static map, like how it can be changed in case of Google Maps API - Here check the setTilt() function. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en

Something similar to that is available for Google static map that can be passed in the url parameter.

Comment: Don't see any way to do that with a [Static Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro), looks like the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) might support it (I see the 45 degree imagery, but I don't see any way to disable it).

Answer (score 5):

Not possible in the Static Maps API.

There's a feature request: [Issue 3796: Enable access to 45° imagery through Static Maps API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3796).

Comment: About to be 2021 and this is still the case :(

Answer (score 4):

I did a workaround to have a tilted static image with JavaScript + html2canvas. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750987/4537906

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Capture map</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      float: left;
      height: 640px;
      width: 640px;
    }
    .myButton1 {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23', GradientType=0);
      background-color: #ffec64;
      -moz-border-radius: 6px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #333333;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 6px 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
    }
    .myButton1:hover {
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64', GradientType=0);
      background-color: #ffab23;
    }
    .myButton1:active {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <a id="btnSave" class="myButton1">generate img</a>
  <a id="togCtrl" class="myButton1">toggle controls</a>
  <div id="img-out"></div>
  <script>
    var map;
    var transform;
    var toggler = true;

    function initialize() {
      var tokio = new google.maps.LatLng(35.6801453, 139.728792);

      var agbar = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4035482, 2.1894355);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: agbar,
        zoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      });


    }

     //forked of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24281734/4537906
     //get transform value

    $("#btnSave").click(function() {
      console.log('btnSave');
      var transform = $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css("transform");
      var comp = transform.split(","); //split up the transform matrix
      var mapleft = parseFloat(comp[4]); //get left value
      var maptop = parseFloat(comp[5]); //get top value
      $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({ //get the map container.
        "transform": "none",
        "left": mapleft,
        "top": maptop,
      })
      html2canvas($('#map'), {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //ready to use with the below commented line
          //location.href = dataUrl; //this opens the image as an url into your browser
          $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            "transform": transform
          })
          $("#img-out").append(canvas);
        }
      });
    });
    $("#togCtrl").click(function() {

      map.setOptions({
        disableDefaultUI: toggler,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: toggler,
        draggable: !toggler,
        scrollwheel: !toggler
      });
      toggler = !toggler;

    })
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```