# Tilt option for google map static API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Am using google map static API. am displaying map by address like below

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%27Budapest-Keleti%20Railway%20Terminal,%20Budapest,%20Hungary%27&zoom=20&size=520x500&markers=%27Budapest-Keleti%20Railway%20Terminal,%20Budapest,%20Hungary%27&maptype=satellite&sensor=false
```

My question is is there any tilt option for Google map Static(Image) api...
Any help will be great appreciated thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change view angle in Google Static Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687617/how-to-change-view-angle-in-google-static-map)

Comment: @miguev that one is google javascript API I am asking in google static maps...

Comment: Yes and no. The question is about Static Maps, and the answers are about both.