# Google Maps displays a blank map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The `div` `#map-canvas` contains a Google map.

I tried following code:

```
$('#map-canvas').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
});

<input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot Of Div" onclick="capture();" />
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

Using this code I am getting a blank map.

[image]

Comment: is the #map-canvas in an iframe in a different domain to the rest of the page?

Comment: why dont you use ajax .that will be great ..even your page wont reload

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046778/html2canvas-does-not-work-with-google-maps-pan) is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/24281734/5336818 Do as directed in this solution

Comment: yes its working thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example) may help you to get map image...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question