# Polygon on google maps taints canvas when using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-maps-api-3, polygon, html2canvas

I have been trying to take a "screenshot" of a map I am working on and was finally able to do it by using a combination of html2canvas and the answer [from this previous SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046778/html2canvas-does-not-work-with-google-maps-pan)

However, when drawing polygons or polylines on the map (either using drawing manager or google.maps.polygon) the canvas suddenly becomes tainted and can't be exported using toDataURL(). The following error is produced following a successful canvas render (http removed due to 2 link max allowance):

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
>       at Object.onrendered (://127.0.0.1/code/WorkingCode.html:188:31)
>       at Object.options.complete (://127.0.0.1/code/html2canvas.js:2711:15)
>       at start (://127.0.0.1/code/html2canvas.js:2215:17)
>       at HTMLImageElement.img.onload (://127.0.0.1/code/html2canvas.js:2352:7)

I have researched this problem for and there is no clear answer why this happens! I know the "screenshot" with polygons should work because the map in the aforementioned link ([also seen here on the web](http://www.justicemap.org/index.php?gsLayer=indian&gfLon=-64.40644531&gfLat=33.75474413&giZoom=4&giAdvanced=1&)) is able to do it.

The difference between our two codes is not clear as to why one would work while the other would not, as I am using the same code.

So I guess I have two questions A) What about the polygons taints the canvas (i.e. is there a file that i should look for a CORS header? B) Why does the same code work in one instance and fail in another.

Some background on my code:
1) I am running everything locally through Xampp server (apache) on windows. 
2) The map is generated through google maps api as are the polygons. 
3) The html2canvas.js is located in the working folder that my webpage is in.

I am attaching some relevant bits of code so that it is hopefully more clear what I am doing.

sources:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIkey&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&callback=initAutoComplete"
async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/LawnCareMapping/html2canvas.js"
></script>
```

Screenshot

```
<button onclick="Calc()"></button>
function Calc(){

         //New Method from StackExchange solution
      //get transform value
      var transform=$('.gm-style>div:first>div').css('transform')
      var comp=transform.split(',') //split up the transform matrix
      var mapleft=parseFloat(comp[4]) //get left value
      var maptop=parseFloat(comp[5])  //get top value
      $('.gm-style>div:first>div').css({ //get the map container. not sure if stable
        'transform':'none',
        'left':mapleft,
        'top':maptop,
      });

      html2canvas($('#map'),
      {
        //proxy: "http://127.0.0.1/html2canvasproxy.php",
        useCORS: true,
        logging: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas)
        {
          var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL();

          window.open (dataUrl);
          $('.gm-style>div:first>div').css({
            left:0,
            top:0,
            'transform':transform
          })
        }
      });
    };
```

Map and polygons

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.886273, -74.870589);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: location,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
          draggableCursor:"crosshair",
        });

Shape && Shape.setMap(null)
  Shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: Points,
    strokeColor:"#fff",
    strokeOpacity: .5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#fff",
    fillOpacity: .5,
    editable: !0,
    clickable: false
  });
plowShape[plowCoordInd].setMap(map);
```

EDIT:

I have removed my website link.

Comment: I get exported images of the map with the polygons (on the live page).  How do we replicate the tainted canvas?  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Does this also occurs in different browsers (e.g try in FF). Does this also occurs in latest html2canvas version?

Comment: @geocodezip - Thanks for the response! I added a link so that you can access my site directly.

Comment: @kaiido - I have tested it under latest IE, FF, and chrome. All 3 produce identical results, where I can save image without polygons, but with polygons taints the canvas. Also, I am using the latest version of html2canvas. Should I try rolling back?

Comment: Latest version of h2c returns a Promise. Your code in the question doesn't use the latest version.

Comment: @kaiido - It looks like you are right. I was using the version dubbed "latest version" from 2013. However, I see there is a 2015 version dubbed "pre-release". I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The issue was due to markers on the map! I had used markers for my search box and I also had a custom marker to indicate a point of interest.

Once I removed the two markers the tainted issue went away and I am able to add polygons now!

To remedy the markers, I am just using custom markers that I upload to my server.